# Magento 2 knockoutjs error data-bind even?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have created custom template with knockoutjs in magento 2.1.7.

The file name **mytemplate.phtml**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "someScope": {
                    "component": "Namespace_Module/js/view/listing"
                    "template": "Namespace_Module/listing"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the content of file **Namespace_Module/web/js/template/listing.html**

```
<a role="button" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="click: myFunction"><span data-bind="i18n: 'click me!'"></span></a>
```

This is the content of file **Namespace_Module/web/js/view/listing.js**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent'
], function($, ko ,Component) {
    'use strict';
    var self = this;

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        },
        /**
         * retrieve data to form update
         */
        myFunction: function () {
            console.log('is ok');
            return this;
        }
    });
})
```

when i load get error message is

> Unable to process binding "click: function (){return myFunction }"

pls let me know, what's wrong in my code? Many thanks!

Comment: make sure, that last version of `Namespace_Module/web/js/view/listing.js` has been loaded by browser

Comment: yes i checked it's last version.

Comment: place `alert` message instead of ` return this` and run `upgrade, static-content:deploy` commands. And try again.

Comment: @xanka what exactly you are looking for inside `myFunction`? Are you going to display any message or print any data?.

Comment: It not important, pls let me know what wrong in my code or any things make code run true.

Comment: try data-bind="click: $parent.myFunction()"

Answer (score -1):

Change button html following way:

```
<a role="button" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="click: myFunction()"><span data-bind="i18n: 'click me!'"></span></a>
```

Change your js function:

```
myFunction: function () {
    console.log('Click Me');
}
```

Make sure you deleted html template from **pub/static/frontend/....**

Comment: Thank @sohelrana, i was change like this but get the samle error message. `Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return myFunction() }"
Message: myFunction is not defined`

Comment: Did you flash browser cache? It’s tested code, should work

Comment: i'm using mode is developer.

Comment: Whatever your mode browser don’t care. Browser cache js and html templates. So need hard refresh.

Comment: i was flush cache ah check file in pub folder, it's lastest version.

Comment: Hi @SohelRana. Can you please look here and help me ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258110/magento-2-knockout-data-bindclick-not-working