# Magento 2 : knockout data-bind:click not working

Tags: magento2, knockout

I added phtml file using ajax response. There are two buttons available in that phtml file.

**Buttons.phtml :**

```
<div id="rh-buttons-temp" class="actions" data-bind="scope:'rh-buttons'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <button type="submit" title="Select" class="action primary" id="rh-select-btn" data-bind="click:addCustomOptions()">
        <span>Select</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" title="Cancel" class="action" id="rh-cancel-btn" data-bind="click:addCustomOptions()">
        <span>Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "rh-buttons": {
                        "component": "RH_Custom/js/knock"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

**MainFile.phtml :**

```
<div id="rh-ko-example" data-bind="scope:'rh-ko-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "rh-ko-scope": {
                        "component": "RH_Custom/js/kotemplate",
                        "template" : "RH_Custom/kotemplate"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    </script>
    <div style="display:none" class="product details product-item-details">
        <div class='custom'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This Buttons.phtml file added in `<div class='custom'></div>` using ajax response.

Now, when click on **Select Button** then **addCustomOptions()** function call should be call. But, it's not working.

---

**EDIT :**

**knock.js**

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'RH_Custom/js/kotemplate'
],
function($,Component,ko,kotemplate) {
    'use strict';
     return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            alert("knock call");
            self = this;
            this._super();
            // kotemplate.addCustomOptions(); 
        },
        addCustomOptions : function()
        {
            console.log('knock custom options');
        }
    });
});
```

alert call successfully on above file. But, `kotemplate.addCustomOptions()` is not working. It returns error :

> Uncaught TypeError: kotemplate.addCustomOptions is not a function

Where I do mistake?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: hi @Rohan, can you update me how can we bind links here?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly call the knockout method. Instead, add `$parent`while calling it. something like below.

```
 <button type="button" title="Cancel" class="action" id="rh-cancel-btn" data-bind="click:$parent.addCustomOptions()">
    <span>Cancel</span>
</button>
```

Comment: If I do $parent.addCustomOptions() then which file function call? RH_Custom/js/kotemplate or RH_Custom/js/knock ?

Comment: It will call directly associated knockout file. like the file associated with Scope :rh-ko-scope

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but may help others:

**in phtml:**

```
<div data-bind="scope:'myscope'">
     <span data-bind="click:testMukesh">test data xyz..</span>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "myscope": {
                        "component": "Magento_Contact/js/contact",
                        "custom_var1": <?= $custom_var1_value?>                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**in js file** contact.js

```
define(['jquery', 'ko', 'domReady!'], function ($, ko) {    
    
    return function (config, element) {
        this.testMukesh = function () {
            alert('test ok..');
        }
   }
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it without paranthesis

**Wrong:**

```
data-bind="click:addCustomOptions()"
```

**Correct:**

```
data-bind="click:addCustomOptions"
```